# Is there a software way to "fully" power my laptop off?

Tags: power-management, battery

DUT: HP Laptop 14z-fq000 20.04

If I power off my laptop from GNOME, the screen goes totally black and the case gets totally cool. The rub is the battery loses 10% charge per day. My guess is something isn't turned off and the loss isn't due to battery self discharge.

If I power off my laptop from GNOME, wait for the screen to go black, and then press and hold the power button for 6 seconds, my laptop turns totally off, or at least the battery doesn't lose any (noticeable) charge over 24 hours.

Is there a software way to "fully" power my laptop off, using the terminal for example? If yes, what is it?

There is a lot of Q&A on this and similar topics but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Many kind thanks in advance for at least reading this far!

Gary

Comment: Starting with OS & release details may help. There is the `shutdown` command (which has an option to turn off power or just shutdown OS & leave power on which is more useful for mid-range or mainframe hardware..)  but there are many methods.

Comment: "Is there a software way to "fully" power my laptop off, using the terminal for example?" No, since the OS is not active it is hardware related so the solution has to be in BIOS. "The rub is the battery loses 10% charge per day" is a hardware problem. 1 thing is important: check BIOS for USB settings for power off. USB can remain active so you can charge an USB device.

Comment: Hey everyone. I should have done more research before asking. My bad! The problem is there with Windoze too. It's not a Ubuntu issue. Sorry to waste the community's time.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will tell the hardware to poweroff using the [standard, published methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) -- that's all it can do.

The Ubuntu developers won't know about an unpublished double-secret poweroff setting, and OEMs are generally unlikely to build in secret features that make their customers surprised and unhappy.

Reach out your OEM hardware support. Some kind of battery-draining hardware fault seems a much more likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the link 535733. After carefully reading it, the acronym FUBAR comes to mind. Thank you for the thoughtful answer and sorry for wasting your and the community's time on an intrinsic hardware issue.